# Which one of the following sentences is more correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, possessives, apostrophe

"Maria's, Mary's and Sophia's first loves was Katarina.

"Katarina was Maria's, Mary's and Sophia's first loves​"

"The first love of Maria's, Mary's and Sophia's was Katarina."

Comment: Did you intentionally make 'love' plural in the first two? They would both work with 'love' instead of 'loves'.

Comment: I’d opt for a rewrite that emphasizes either Katrina as the first love of others or what the three girls/women have in common—they have all loved Katrina. And get rid of the distraction of punctuation.

Comment: Are you saying they *shared* a single love (there was a group of four people involved romantically at the same time), or are you saying that Maria love Katerina as her first love, then Mary loved Katerina as her first love, and then Sophia loved Katerina as her first love? I strongly suspect the latter (although it's strange in practical terms, where it would be at least more probable that they each loved different people named Katarina, rather than the same Katarina), which means it should be *loves* ***were***.) In short, none of the sentences seem to be correct.

Comment: Note that with something that is jointly possessed, the apostrophe only goes on the *last* noun. The apostrophe goes on each noun only if the possessions are independent. That's why knowing the context here (and the singularity or plurality) is essential.

Comment: "The first love of Maria, Mary and Sophia was Katarina." The double-possessive is a tricky device, and is not the better option here.

Comment: Something is either correct or incorrect. So you cannot ask which sentence is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the second statement in your list but with a correction - "*Katarina was Maria's, Mary's and Sophia's first **love***."

It looks simpler than the rest.

The first sentence also looks fine, but again with the small correction - *"Maria's, Mary's and Sophia's first **love** was Katarina.*

The last sentence would be my last preference.

Although, I should add that the order of preference will vary depending on what you're trying to emphasize.

Hope this helps.

NS